# Image attached and Loaded....yet getOffsetWidth/height still zero

Tags: gwt

This ones really baffling me.
I have a composite widget wrapping a Image with the following load handler set;

```
ONLOADHANDLE = SceneObjectIcon.imageContents.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {         
        @Override
        public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {

            Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand(){
                @Override
                public void execute() {

                    ObjectsLog("Size          ="+getObjectWidth()+","+getObjectHeight(),"green");            //0,0 
                    ObjectsLog("is Attached   ="+SceneObjectIcon.isAttached(),"green");                     //true
                    ObjectsLog("is Attached   ="+SceneObjectIcon.imageContents.isAttached(),"green");        //true                                             
                    ObjectsLog("offset        ="+SceneObjectIcon.imageContents.getOffsetWidth()+","+SceneObjectIcon.imageContents.getOffsetHeight(),"green");            //0,0  
                    ObjectsLog("image itself  ="+SceneObjectIcon.imageContents.getWidth()      +","+SceneObjectIcon.imageContents.getHeight(),      "green");        // works       

                    //remove handler so this wont fire on subsequent loads
                    ONLOADHANDLE.removeHandler();

                    //run other stuff
                    imageloaded();                      
                }                   
            });

        }

    });
```

*Notes;*

SceneObjectIcon is a class that extends Composite. It wraps a Image object called "imageContents" ie just;

```
initWidget(imageContents);
```

The class contains functions mostly for animation of the images. However, thats not being used here.

ObjectsLog is just a class that handles logging for me. Consider it just like Log.info or such.

-
As you can see the code sets a deferred command onLoad, which in turn logs the size of the Image that just loaded.

However the "offset" size returned by the logs is always 0,0 - despite the fact both "is Attached" statements returned true, and this is only triggered after both waiting for the load and the browser.
The Image size in the last log statement is, however, being picked up correctly.

Any ideas what I could  be doing wrong?

Aside from scheduleDeferred, I also tried scheduleFinnally and scheduleEntry with the same results.

When should getOffsetWidth() be available, and what factors other then what I have tried could influence not getting a result?

I am using GWT 2.7, running a local server for testing, if that makes a difference.

Comment: What is SceneObjectIcon?

Comment: sorry about that, added the information.

Comment: Check in your browser dev tools whether this object actually has a height other than zero when rendered.

Comment: Can you show how you are attaching the `imageContents`, to what parent, and what kind of styling is going on? You can at least be sure that it is attached, as if it wasn't, you wouldn't even be getting the load handler going off (unless you attached it, then removed it from the dom somehow).

Comment: Just a guess, can it be that the imageContents has changed to an other Image?